# How do I send a html content in mail body using python?

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, email

I am sending a mail by reading an excel file using pandas as dataframe. Then I am converting that dataframe using df.to_html with CSS style wrapped. Below is my code.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import email.message
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import email
import smtplib
import xlrd
filename = 'exl_sheet.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
html_string = '''
<html>
  <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
  {table}
  </body>
</html>.
             '''
df_html = html_string.format(table=df.to_html(classes='mystyle'))
sender = "sender@gmail.com"
receiver = "receiver@gmail.com"
password = 'xxxxxxxxx'
server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
msg = email.message.EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Train Data'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver
msg = MIMEText(df_html, 'html')
print(msg)
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(sender, password)
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg)
server.quit()
```

The output of print(msg) is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq7lm.jpg)

However, the message I am receiving is as below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQgGH.jpg)

That is I am not receiving the table with style. Please suggest.

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/link-element/link-in-head/

Comment: And if you put your css on the <head>???

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe that only inline styles are supported on email -- at least that's all you can depend on across all email clients. For example, Gamil strips out all `<head>` and `<body>` tags. Try adding `style` parameters to your HTML tags, for example:

```
<span style="color: red;">I am red</span>
```

Even if you could have external style sheets, you specified: `href="df_style.css"`, which is a relative URL. If you sent that email to me, would I have that stylesheet on my PC? You would need to make it an absolute URL, such as `href="http://demo.com/df_syle.css"`. Keep this in mind when you reference other items in your email, such as images.